# How to implement custom window in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want to implement a custom window in flutter such as in youtube add button.
How to implement this type of window?

Thanks in advance.
[youtube create button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wEqw.jpg)
[create window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOMcS.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use showModalBottomSheet()
here is the documentation and a simple example [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)